# Reading data from /dev/usb/lp0 linux

Tags: linux, printing, label, cat

I have label printer Wincode LP433 and can print using command

`cat file.prn > /dev/usb/lp0`

How I can read data from `/dev/usb/lp0`?

Answer (score 0):

simply call:

```
cat /dev/usb/lp0
```

that should work if your printer supports bi-directional communication via usb.

Tested with a Zebra label printer this way:

```
$> echo "~HQES" > /dev/usb/lp0 && cat /dev/usb/lp0
  PRINTER STATUS                            
   ERRORS:         0 00000000 00000000      
   WARNINGS:       0 00000000 00000000
```